# Magento 2 - Get Categories by Custom Category Attribute

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, category-listing

In Magento2 - I've created a **yes/no toggle category attribute named `is_featured`**, its shown as "Homepage Category" in the screenshot below.

[image]

I'd like to be able to display (on the homepage cms page) all categories with this category attribute set to yes, I'd need to grab the **category title, url, thumbnail etc**, does anyone have any recommended steps on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Below is the standard way to achieve it.

```
    namespace NameSpace\Module\Block;


    class FeaturedCategories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{


     protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getFeaturedCategories()
    {
        $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured_category', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', '1')
            ->setPageSize(10)
            ->setCurPage(1);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we use this on rest api response, I tried with extension attribute that's not working. I am trying to get this attribute in this Api, rest/V1/categories/list?searchCriteria[pageSize]=0

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code to filter with `is_featured` is yes

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
        $category->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured',['eq'=>1])
        ->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');
```

**try its work for me**